# Ionic Content-Security-Policy not found (but is included)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm having the following error:

> No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using
>   the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.

I've included it in my config.xml

```
  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
  <access origin="*"/>
```

I know the is the 'unsafe' way to wire it up, but I'm just trying to get it working before narrowing it down.  I've also tried narrowing it down without any luck.

I remember I went through and added an after hook when trying to make it function with ios, however I'm using android now and am at a loss.  Any ideas? (the plugin is installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this meta tag for **content-security-policy** into your index.html file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I had to play with the content allowances to allow certain things but it got me there, Thanks!